# Como filtrar um List<Dictionary<string, object>>?

Tags: c#

Possuo uma variavel listaMatriz que é um List>.

Ela possui 108 itens.

O listaMatriz[0] é assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O que eu queria é que a variavel listaMatrizFiltrada viesse apenas com os itens da listaMatriz cujo COD_OCUPACAO = 1 && COD_NIVEL = 1

Tentei de diversas formas, exemplo:

```
var listaMatrizFiltrada = listaMatriz.GroupBy(i => i.ElementAt(0).Value == 1 && i.ElementAt(4).Value == 1).Where(group => @group.Any()).Select(g => g.First()).ToDictionary(kvp => kvp.Keys, kvp => kvp.Values);
```

Mas não filtrou corretamente. Esse código eu achei na internet, mas ainda não entendi exatamente como funciona cada trecho (GroupBy, Where, etc).

Comment: Realmente isto não faz muito sentido. Procure mostrar um contexto maior de como está usando estas lista com dicionário. Quando tem uma coleção dentro da outra é pouco mais complicado mesmo. E eu estou achando que a solução alternativa que dei na outra pergunta usando `ExpandoObject` pode ser mais adequada e mais simples de manipular. Não posso garantir porque não sei exatamente todas suas necessidades. Você está querendo agrupar alguma coisa ou isto foi colocando tentando resolver o problema do filtro simples? Você pode garantir que todos os dicionários tem estas duas chaves do filtro?

Comment: Muito obrigado mais uma vez @bigown, antes de responder a você fui testar a solução do Cigano e realmente funcionou. Eu usei o groupby apenas pra resolver o problema do filtro e todos os dicionarios tem aquela duas chaves sim.

Comment: Poderia criar uma matriz, de segunda dimensão, no caso em Visual Basic seria `Dim listaMatrizFiltrada As Object(,) = {{item1, item2}, {item3, item4}}` etc...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dá pra simplificar muito mais isso aí:

```
var listaMatrizFiltrada = listaMatriz
                          .Where(item => item["COD_OCUPACAO"] == 1 &&         
                                           item["COD_NIVEL"] == 1)
                          .ToList();
```

Como `ListaMatriz` é uma lista de dicionários, `item` será um `Dictionary<string, object>`, portanto posso usar índices como `item["COD_OCUPACAO"]` e `item["COD_NIVEL"]`.

Estou supondo que isto é uma extração de um banco de dados, e que todos os dicionários da lista possuem os mesmos índices.

Comment: Perfeito! Era exatamente isso! A única coisa que precisei fazer foi converter item["COD_OCUPACAO"] e item["COD_NIVEL"] em inteiros aí funcionou.